# briannesbitt/Carbon count diff between 2 dates and display them in a propper way

Tags: php, datetime

I want to calculate the difference between 2 dates, that works, but is there a function to show a format like this:

- 1 month
- 1 year
- 4 hours

And so on, as you know what I mean.

So perhaps, I ban a user for 2 hours, then it needs to display the user is banned for 2 hours.

By calculating the expire time and banned_at time.

This is what I have now:

```
date_diff(date_create(\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ban->banned_on)), date_create(\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ban->expire)))->format('d-m-y');
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$bannedAt = '2015-10-05 10:00:00';
$banLength = 2;

$banTill = Carbon::parse($bannedAt)->addHours($banLength);
$now = Carbon::now();

// If now is less than or equal to banTill then remaining minutes is the difference between now and bantill. Else, the remaining minutes is 0
$remainingBanSeconds = $now->lte($banTill)?$now->diffInSeconds($banTill):0;

echo echo gmdate('H \h\o\u\r\s\, i \m\i\n\u\t\e\s \a\n\d s \s\e\c\o\n\d\s', $remainingBanSeconds);
```

Comment: Okay, I understand what you say. But my problem is, it needs to calculate the time between 2 datetime objects. Not a datetime object and a string like 2hour. But it needs to say solething like '`2 weeks 4 days and 7 hours remaining untill the ban is lifted`'. So I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: see updated answer. you can get the remaining seconds, and use gmdate to get the hours, minutes and seconds. http://us3.php.net/gmdate

Comment: I think you don't understand it. I have 2 tables with a `datetime` format in. For example; `2015-10-06 19:59:01` = Banned on and `2015-11-06 19:59:04` is the expire time. So it needs to calculate how long the ban left.